# PostgreSQL - Performance Issue - Self-join on big table to find record on consecutive days needs table materialize and it is slow

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

I have a huge table in a PostgresSQL db, called `big_table`.

The key is composed of multiple columns: a date column, called `date_id`, and multiple string columns (for simplicity let's say there is only 1 string column called `str_id`).

The query I want to execute is:

```
SELECT count (distinct a.str_id)
FROM
    big_table a JOIN big_table b
    ON a.date_id = (b.date_id + interval '1 day') AND a.str_id = b.str_id
```

The (expensive) explain plan I get is:

```
Aggregate  (cost=247348767.01..247348767.04 rows=1 width=8)
  ->  Merge Join  (cost=67997554.72..236925087.00 rows=4169472007 width=12)
        Merge Cond: ((a.date_id = ((b.date_id + '1 day'::interval))) AND ((a.str_id)::text = (b.str_id)::text))
        ->  Sort  (cost=33998777.36..34428507.76 rows=171892160 width=16)
              Sort Key: a.date_id, a.str_id
              ->  Seq Scan on big_table a  (cost=0.00..8765967.80 rows=171892160 width=16)
        ->  Materialize  (cost=33998777.36..34858238.16 rows=171892160 width=16)
              ->  Sort  (cost=33998777.36..34428507.76 rows=171892160 width=16)
                    Sort Key: ((b.date_id + '1 day'::interval)), b.str_id
                    ->  Seq Scan on big_table b  (cost=0.00..8765967.80 rows=171892160 width=16)
JIT:
  Functions: 16
  Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true
```

I've already created two indexes (with no changes to the plan):

```
CREATE INDEX index_1 ON big_table(date_id, str_id);
CREATE INDEX index_2 ON big_table((date_id + interval '1 day'), str_id);
```

How can I optimize this query?

Comment: Hitting an index is not instant.  Hitting one 171,892,160 times it not obviously faster than the current plan is.  You could do `set enable_mergejoin TO off` to see if that persuades it to use the index.

Comment: Did you `vacuum analyze big_table;` or at least `analyze big_table;` after setting up the indexes?